# Python list not returning correct value of complex object

Tags: python-3.x, list, pygame, pygame-surface

I am writing a platformer game using python 3.6.9 & the pygame library. I'm trying to create all of the game objects, then put them all in a list in order to blit them all to the screen in a `for x in gameObjectList` loop.

Each of the game objects in question has an attribute img, which I assign to `pygame.image.load("slime-character.gif")`. 
This stores the image as a pygame.Surface object. 
The window (screen) has a function blit, that takes a Surface object (which is an image) and either an x and y coordinate pair or a pygame.Rect, which it takes the x and y from.

My code does:

```
for x in gameObjects:
        screen.blit(x.img, x.rect)
```

but it throws an error, saying that x.img is an int. Printing this, it appears to be 200. Printing this without the iterator `print(gameObjects[0].img)` gives me the same thing.

BUT, if I print the object's value itself `print(object1.img)` I get out a pygame.Surface object, which is what I need to blit.

It's impractical for me to hardcode every possible object to appear, so I need to refer to their images from a list of the objects. But when I do, it gives me an incorrect datatype. Does anyone know why this is happening/a workaround so I can access the data I need?

Thanks in advance. [Link to full code (89ish lines) on Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POC1Xc8YKykBG6nJOetWXUpY0Odd7B-q/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT: solved thanks to a comment by Chris Doyle: I'd forgotten to put screen as a parameter for movableObjs. I'm leaving this question up though, in case anyone can explain the program's behavior (working without list but failing when referred to from a list).

Comment: you should probably call the suppor method to inititae gameObj in movableObj. I suspect the issue is the way you are directly calling the init method of gameobj, you pass in movableobj as the first arg,  img as the second arg, and xpos as the 3rd object. in your init method this means that movableobj will be self, img will be screen and xpos wil lbe img in gameObj.

Comment: maybe try initalising your parent class as `super(movableObj, self).__init__(screen, img, xpos, ypos, w, h, visible, active)` instead of calling its init method directly

Comment: @ChrisDoyle after looking at your first message, I went over the init methods and the constructors again. Turns out I missed putting screen into movableObj.
I'm not sure why the code was working without the list before, so I'll leave the question up in case someone can explain its behavior, but thank you for helping me fix it.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Class names should normally use the CapWords convention. See [Style Guide for Python Code - Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).
Use rename `gameObjectRef` by `GameObjectRef`, `gameObj` by `GameObj` and `movableObj` by `MovableObj`.

---

The issue is `object2` respectively the class `movableObj`. The class `movableObj` is derived from the class `gameObj`. The first argument to the constructor of `gameObj` is screen. You have to pass `screen` to the constructor of `gameObj` in the super call o fht constructor:

Do

<s>`gameObj.__init__(self, img, xpos, ypos, w, h, visible, active)`</s>

```py
gameObj.__init__(self, screen, img, xpos, ypos, w, h, visible, active)
```

in

```py
class movableObj(gameObj):
    def __init__(self, screen, img, xpos, ypos, w, h, gravity=1, xvel=0, yvel=0,
                 visible=False, leaveScreen=False, active=True):
        gameObj.__init__(self, screen, img, xpos, ypos, w, h, visible, active)
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.xvel = xvel
        self.yvel = yvel
        self.leaveScreen = leaveScreen
```

Further more you have to pass `screen` to the constructor when you create an instance of `movableObj`:

<s>`object2 = movableObj(imgslime, 600, 200, 20, 20, 0, 2, 0)`</s>

```py
object2 = movableObj(screen, imgslime, 600, 200, 20, 20, 0, 2, 0)
```